# AWS CodeDeploy deployment tracking

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

I would like to know if it's possible to track the deployment status of CodeDeploy by using CLI.
Currently, I'm using Bamboo to trigger the CodeDeploy deployment by CLI using: aws deploy create-deployment ... My Bamboo plan will show green the moment the deployment is triggered instead of checking if the actual deployment is succeeded. Is there a way to let Bamboo/command line verify if the actual deployment was successfully deployed?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `create-deployment` will return a Deployment ID. Use that in `aws deploy get-deployment --deployment-id XXX` to see the status and info of the deployment:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/deploy/get-deployment.html

You can use `aws deploy wait deployment-successful --deployment-id XXX` to wait for completion:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/deploy/wait/deployment-successful.html.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest you use the AWS Code Deployment Task to manage these deployments. It will manage the entire process, and will report on actual deployment status.

> With the AWS CodeDeploy task for Bamboo you can deploy applications to
>   EC2 instances automatically, reliably, and rapidly. Additionally, AWS
>   CodeDeploy keeps track of the whole deployment process.

See https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/using-the-aws-codedeploy-task-750396059.html